# How to get first letter from string using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am poor knowledge in jquery. I have mentioned the script below

```
var header = $('.time'+col).text();
alert(header);
```

I got string as "109:00AM" from that how to get first letter such as 1.
Could you please help me.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Try with `charAt(0)` like

```
var header = $('.time'+col).text();
alert(header.charAt(0));
```

You can also use `substring` like

```
alert(header.substring(1));
```

And as **@Jai** said you can use `slice` also like

```
alert(header.slice(0,1));
```

Comment: `.slice(0, 1)` too...

Comment: Thanku @Jai I have added that now in my ans

Comment: That is not me who downvoted it. see i liked your comment.

Comment: FYI alert(header.substring(1)) in your post here gives entire string *except* the first character, I think you want alert(header.substring(0,1)); - syntax of substring is (start,end) so you want only the first character it's start at charcter 0 end at character 1 (not including character 1)